# How do I download this type of file using php?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

So,I'm trying to automate downloading images from picjumbo.com site.So far most things worked like finding img src and find it's image etc.But when I try to download the image all I get is an html file(open those files with notepad++ to view it).How do I download the file after loading that page? I'm putting my code below.Everything works except getting that final image! :(

How do I download that image ?
file Download page : http://picjumbo.com/download/?d=IMG_3642.jpg
How do I save that image after the page load??

thanks!

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$file = "http://picjumbo.com/";


$files = file_get_contents($file);
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load($files);  


foreach($html->find('img[class=image]') as $element){
    $img_src = explode('/',$element->src);
    $img_src  = explode('-',$img_src[5]);
    $img = $img_src[0];
    $url = 'http://picjumbo.com/download?d='.$img.'.jpg';
    copy($url, 'images/'.$img); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting an HTML page when you try to download that link instead of the image is because that page is an HTML page, not an image.  If you click on it, it takes you to an HTML page rather than to an image.  Now once that page is loaded, it redirects you to downloading the image using this on line 12 of the HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d=IMG_3642.jpg">
```

So the URL image is this:

```
http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d=IMG_3642.jpg
```

In order to download this image, you'd have to gather this HTML page into a variable, and parse through it in some way to grab the URL from this, and then use `file_get_contents()` to download the image.  To parse through this, you could use something like `SimpleHTMLDOM` to read it in, or since you're just looking for the one tag, if it appears consistently in the document, you could just pull out line 12 then use some creative `substr()` action to get the URL.

Comment: He _is_ using Simple HTML DOM.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but not to locate the proper element. He needs to find the `<meta>` tag to get the proper URL to download. I was just trying to be thorough. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The URL redirects to a page that uses Javascript to start a separate download. If you watch what happens in the Network tab of the browser's Developer Tools, you'll see that the actual URL of the image is:

```
http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d=$img.jpg
```